How to set web-renderer html in Android Studio debug mode?
I have a flutter web application that displays some network images, but I can only show the images correctly by command "flutter run --web-renderer html" or build with html renderer, and is not able to show them by clicking the "run" button for debug purpose.
I am not sure where to set this as default in Android Studio (version 2021.3.1).
Thank you.
